# PHP XML why I can't read the first attribute with SimpleXML?

Tags: php, simplexml

The XML file I want to read looks like this:

```
<issues aaa="444" exportTime="Tue Jul 28 23:54:39 CEST 2015">
  <issue>
   <name>Testing</name>
```

I use this code:

```
$simple = file_get_contents('/url/test3.xml');
$test = new SimpleXMLElement($simple);
```

I can read the issue name children:

```
echo $test->issue[1]->name;
```

How can I read issues ExportTime value?

```
echo $test->issues[exportTime]
```

doesn't do anything.

Comment: `echo $test['exportTime'];`

Comment: do var_dump($test) and then see the entire build

Comment: splash58, Daniel Krom: thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php

$str = <<<XML
<issues aaa="444" exportTime="Tue Jul 28 23:54:39 CEST 2015">
  <issue>
   <name>Testing</name>
  </issue>
</issues>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
var_dump($xml['exportTime']);

?>
```

OUTPUT

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
  public 0 => string 'Tue Jul 28 23:54:39 CEST 2015' (length=29)
```